I use List In SwiftUI where I get data from API and I want to sort them in section with similar titles
I have API data
    var id: Int
    var category: String
    var thumbnail: String
    var brand: String
    var description: String
    var title: String
}


and I have List where I have to section products with similar titles...
like Smartphones in one section
laptops in one sections etc.
I don't know what kind of titles will come in future so it has to be logic.
my list code:

struct LandingView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: LandingViewModel
    init() {
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: LandingViewModel())
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if viewModel.isLoading {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                List {
                    ForEach(viewModel.products) { product in
                        Section {
                            HStack {
                                AsyncImage(url: URL(string: product.thumbnail)) { image in
                                    image
                                        .resizable()
                                        .scaledToFit()
                                        .frame(maxWidth: 100, maxHeight: 100)
                                } placeholder: {
                                    ProgressView()
                                        .progressViewStyle(.circular)
                                }
                                .padding()
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                                    Text(product.title)
                                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    Text(product.brand)
                                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                    Text("Price $569")
                                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                    Text(product.description)
                                        .font(.subheadline)
                                        .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                                        .lineLimit(3)
                                }
                                StepperCustombutton(stepperQuantity: $viewModel.stepCount)
                            }
                        }
                    header: {
                        Text(product.category)
                    }
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            Task{ await viewModel.fetchMyDataWithAsync()}
        })
    }
}

I attach picture as well....

any advices?

I don't know what kind of titles will come in future so it has to be logic. I would prefer the Backend side in this scenario, they can group data for you. Or you can group them in alphabetical order like the Contact app.

Does this answer your question? Dynamically create section for list in SwiftUI
